# tikz: how to rotate an ellipse in this context?

Tags: tikz-pgf

how can I rotate an ellipse in this context without using the draw command?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[anchor = south west, inner sep = 0] (image) {\includegraphics[width = 0.53\paperwidth, height = 15cm, keepaspectratio] {image}};

\begin{scope}[shift={(image.south west)},x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]

\foreach[count=\i] \mypath in {

     {(0.10,0.55) rectangle (0.25,0.65)
      (0.55,0.20) ellipse   (0.10 and 0.05)}
     }{

  \filldraw<\i>[white,opacity=0.75,even odd rule] (0,0) rectangle (1,1) \mypath;            
  \draw<\i>[blue, thick] \mypath;     
  }   

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot,
Harry

Comment: Your code is not compilable. Also, could you add a sketch of what you want? Btw, why don't you want to use `\draw`?

Comment: You can use `ellipse[rotate=30,x radius=.25, y radius=0.05]`. The next time, please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) and no need to say "thanks" in the question ;)

Comment: @Kpym okay...but now I can say: it works, thanks a lot ;-)

Comment: @JouleV: I received errors using draw in my example. Btw, I had no problems compiling the code...